# How to perform a DISTINCT in Pig Latin on a subset of columns?

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to perform a DISTINCT operation on a subset of the columns.  The [documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#distinct) says this is possible with a nested foreach:

> You cannot use DISTINCT on a subset of fields; to do this, use FOREACH and a nested block to first select the fields and then apply DISTINCT (see Example: Nested Block).

It is simple to perform a DISTINCT operation on all of the columns:

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (a1,a2,a3,a4);
A_unique = DISTINCT A;
```

Lets say that I am interested in performing the distinct across a1, a2, and a3. Can anyone provide an example showing how to perform this operation with a nested foreach as suggested in the documentation?

Here's an example of input and expected output:

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS(a1,a2,a3,a4);
DUMP A;

(1 2 3 4)
(1 2 3 4)
(1 2 3 5)
(1 2 4 4)

-- insert DISTINCT operation on a1,a2,a3 here:
-- ...

DUMP A_unique;

(1 2 3 4)
(1 2 4 4)
```

Comment: Could you provide example input and expected output?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Group on all the other columns, project just the columns of interest into a bag, and then use `FLATTEN` to expand them out again:

```
A_unique =
    FOREACH (GROUP A BY a4) {
        b = A.(a1,a2,a3);
        s = DISTINCT b;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(s), group AS a4;
    };
```

Comment: Very nice example!  Thanks for the help.  This is really similar to my answer using distinct, but is much more concise.

Comment: how can we enable parallel clause on it. I tried using DEFAULT_PARALLEL 512 in my script but that doesn't work and #of reducers are not limited to 512. Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is one great solution but, in case you want to reorder the fields in the output (something I had to do recently) this might not work. Here's an alternative:

```
A = LOAD '$input' AS (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5);
GP = GROUP A BY (f1, f2, f3);
OUTPUT = FOREACH GP GENERATE 
    group.f1, group.f2, f4, f5, group.f3 ;
```

When you group on certain fields, the selection would have unique values for the group in a each tuple.

Answer (score 1):

For your specified input/output, the following works.  You might update your test vectors to clarify what you need that is different than this.

```
A_unique = DISTINCT A;
```

Comment: Yeah that might help :). I updated the expected output in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 possible solutions, are there any other good approaches?

Solution 1 (using LIMIT 1):

```
A = LOAD 'test_data' AS (a1,a2,a3,a4);

-- Combine the columns that I want to perform the distinct across into a tuple
A2 = FOREACH A GENERATE TOTUPLE(a1,a2,a3) AS combined, a4 as a4

-- Group by the combined column
grouped_by_a4 = GROUP A2 BY combined;

grouped_and_distinct = FOREACH grouped_by_a4 {
        single = LIMIT A2 1;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(single);
};
```

Solution 2 (using DISTINCT):

```
A = LOAD 'test_data' AS (a1,a2,a3,a4);

-- Combine the columns that I want to perform the distinct across into a tuple
A2 = FOREACH A GENERATE TOTUPLE(a1,a2,a3) AS combined, a4 as a4

-- Group by the other columns (those I don't want the distinct applied to)
grouped_by_a4 = GROUP A2 BY a4;

-- Perform the distinct on a projection of combined and flatten 
grouped_and_distinct = FOREACH grouped_by_a4 {
        combined_unique = DISTINCT A2.combined;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(combined_unique);
};
```

Comment: These solutions are not equivalent.  The first one will only give you two tuples, as there are only two unique combinations of `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`, and the value for `a4` is not predictable.  The second will give output consistent with your sample output.  (It's not as concise as it could be, though.)

Answer (score 0):

```
unique_A = FOREACH (GROUP A BY (a1, a2, a3)) {
    limit_a = LIMIT A 1;
    GENERATE FLATTEN(limit_a) AS (a1,a2,a3,a4);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do the same: "I would like to perform a DISTINCT operation on a subset of the columns". The way I did it was:

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS(a1,a2,a3,a4);
interested_fields = FOREACH A GENERATE a1,a2,a3;
distinct_fields= DISTINCT interested_fields;
final_answer = FOREACH distinct_fields GENERATE FLATTEN($0);
```

I know it's not an example of how to perform a nested foreach as suggested in the documentation; but it's a way of doing a distinct over a subset of fields. Hope It helps to anyone who gets here just like I did.